# Can google dataflow job process the data from google spanner change stream record when it is stopped and then resumes

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-spanner

I am currently working on a dataflow job which picks data from spanner change stream  and write it into another spanner table after some transformation and it works fine. But my doubt is if the dataflow job fails sometime due to unavailability of resources or someother exception and when it resumes once it gets the resources, will it process the change stream records that got inserted to the table when the dataflow job was down. If  yes any specific configuration needs to be done on windowing or the timestamp on when the change stream?

Any help would be appreciated!

I know in kafka we have offset location which is like a bookmark from where the job can continue processing the records, not sure about change stream

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the errors happen during the Dataflow job running process, from https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors,

Dataflow processes elements in arbitrary bundles and retries the complete bundle when an error is thrown for any element in that bundle. When running in batch mode, bundles including a failing item are retried four times. The pipeline fails completely when a single bundle fails four times. When running in streaming mode, a bundle including a failing item is retried indefinitely, which might cause your pipeline to permanently stall.

Comment: thanks for replying @XQHu, my doubt is what happens when the dataflow which is listening to a change stream fails due to memory issue and what happends to the change stream records which got processed during that time

Comment: It still retries. You should check the logs (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/troubleshoot-oom#find-errors) and you might need to change the machine type.

Comment: thanks for the reply @XQHu, so is there a checkpoint mechanism in spanner change stream like in kafka...as the time the dataflow job listens to change stream depends on the timestamp provided in withInclusiveStartAt(com.google.cloud.Timestamp.now()))  and if the dataflow stops and restarts, the change stream records which got inserted during the restart in   not processed in dataflow. Is there a way to handle it.

Comment: Have you observed this problem? This sounds like a bug to me. If this is the case, I suggest you should contact the Dataflow customer support team to open a ticket to track this.